# What is the process of JVM loading shared libraries?

Tags: java, linux, jvm

When 32 bit and 64 bit native shared libraries are installed on a Linux machine, how does the JVM select what to choose, and how does it actually know which one to choose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The programs javac and java have been linked to use certain libraries. Just run a command like this:

```
ldd /extra/JDK8u5/jdk1.8.0_05/bin/java

linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb7846000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libpthread.so.0 (0xb7819000)
libjli.so => /home/extra/JDK8u5/jdk1.8.0_05/bin/../lib/i386/jli/libjli.so (0xb7804000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libdl.so.2 (0xb77ff000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6 (0xb769c000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb7847000)
```

Comment: Ok these are the linkers pre-defined for native libraries right? For example user defined libraries are present in linux system and these are assigned to $LD_LIBRARY_PATH which contains both 32-bit libraries and 64-bit libraries. How does it decide which one to take? Where does linker come into picture in this case? and what is the logic behind it?

Comment: E.g. for gcc: The paths to libraries to use are partly built into the compiler, and may be added to in the build command. The distinction between 32- and 64-bit is due to a selection of the target machine. (There is also the possibility of having different object formats with the same HW architecture as e.g. between RedHat3 and RedHat4; again a matter of selecting the target when cross compiling.)